# Unable to connect android phone to pc for debugging

Tags: android

I am using Samsung galaxy y duos GT s6102. It is a gingerbread phone. I am trying to learn developing apps for android platform. I can test my apps on the simulator but not on my device.
I have used the following troubleshoot methods:

1. Install/Reinstall google usb driver.
2. Format My phone.
3. Usb debugging is ON on my phone .
4. I also also tried [this link](http://www.androidsim.net/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html) but noting helped.
5. There are no drivers available on windows update too.
6. Adb devices also does not give any results.
7. The device is detected in device manager in other devices as
   SAMSUNG.

PS: I am using windows 7.

Comment: Seriously, have you tried to quit and open eclipse, restart phone after all these steps.. That is what helped me once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Samsung Kies:

http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/

Once installed, it also installs Samsung USB drivers

Comment: installing samsung kies helped me.
So this could be closed now.